# Typescript and breeze returning observable array from a query

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, breeze

I am just trying to return an observable array from a breeze.js query.

## Problem

How do I return the data from  a breeze js query as an onservable array if I want to invoke it using a method call in typescript.

Details:The function getAllFileStructures(callback) does not return the observable array data in the promise. I want to invoke a query with breeze and get the data back. I created testgetAllFileStructures to showcase what I want getAllFileStructures to do.

### testgetAllFileStructures returns the following

[image]

## HTML

```
        <script src="~/Scripts/Custom/filerepo/filestructure.DataContext.js"></script>

    <script>

        function load() {
            var SimpleListModel2 = function () {
                var DbCtx = new DataContext.FileStructure("breeze/FileRepoBreeze/");
                this.items = DbCtx.testgetAllFileStructures();
//in a perfect world i would be able to change this to getAllFileStructures() and it will //just work.

        }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model

            ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel2(), document.getElementById("test"));
        }

        window.onload = load;


    </script>



    <div id="test">
        <select multiple="multiple"  data-bind="options: items"> </select>
        </div>
```

## Typescript file

```
module DataContext {
    export class FileStructure {
        private EntityQuery: breeze.EntityQuery;
        private Manager: breeze.EntityManager;

        constructor(MainController: string) {
            //validate the format api/BreezeController/  
            this.EntityQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery;
            this.Manager = this.configureBreezeManager('breeze/FileRepoBreeze/');
        }
        private configureBreezeManager(MainController: string) {
            breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
            return new breeze.EntityManager(MainController);
        }

         public getAllFileStructures(callback) {
             //define the query

            var query =
                this.EntityQuery
                    .from('GetAllFiles')
                    .using(this.Manager).execute()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        return callback(data);
                    })
                    .fail(this.queryFailed);
         }
        public testgetAllFileStructures (){

            var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray();    
            myObservableArray.push('Some TEST'); 
            return myObservableArray;
        }

         public queryFailed(error) {
             alert(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in TypeScript but you are pushing 'Some TEST' into your observable so of course that is what is going to be returned.  You need to return the data.results from your query or store them in an observable and return that.

```
 public getAllFileStructures() {
    var query =
        this.EntityQuery
            .from('GetAllFiles')
            .using(this.Manager).execute()
            .then(function (data) {
                var someObservable = ko.observableArray();
                return someObservable(data.results);
            })
            .fail(this.queryFailed);
 }
```

That will return an observable filled with your data results.  If you are trying to pass in an observable and then fill it you would do it like this -

```
 var myObservable = ko.observableArray();
 getAllFileStructures(myObservable);

 public getAllFileStructures(myObservable) {
    var query =
        this.EntityQuery
            .from('GetAllFiles')
            .using(this.Manager).execute()
            .then(function (data) {
                return myObservable(data.results);
            })
            .fail(this.queryFailed);
 }
```

As far as why you have a script defined in your HTML instead of in your TypeScript class and what you are doing with it, I can't help you there.  I would suggest moving that view model logic to your TypeScript class but that is up to you.  From my understanding you can still define your view model after your TypeScript definition in standard JavaScript, but you will have to figure that one out!

Comment: the viewmodel is embedded in the html because  just a sample I just dint bother to create a viewmodel.js file. I am working on binding it and seing if it works thank you for the help. I will rate once I get it working.

Comment: In typescript myObservable data is not passed by reference. So it is better to return callback(data.results) on the promise.